# Pagination not working while using custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a website where On the home page I show all the posts of the website but now the requirement is to show all the posts excluding 3 Categories, but when I updated my WP_Query accordingly, Now Pagination started showing posts in loop, so Right now I am showing 12 posts in one page, so after 12 posts it repeats from the first post again and so one (right now my pagination is linked with infinite scroll but even if I disable infinite scroll, and switch to normal pagination, the issue still remains.

Below is my custom query

```
      $fullquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=-12,-34,-56' );
      while ($fullqury->have_posts()) : $fullqury->the_post();
```

And Below is my Pagination Code

```
     <?php 
         $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
                        
         echo paginate_links( array(
         'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
         'format' => '?paged=%#%',
         'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
         'total' => $fullquery->max_num_pages
         ) );
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
I'm not use the WP native pagination.
Actually I emptied the code in pagination.php

In your template.php, where you want to place your pagination

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="pagination">
       <?php pagination_bar( $loop ); ?>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the same template in the loop add :

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

And in your function.php (theme child)

```
// Pagination 
function pagination_bar( $custom_query ) {

    $total_pages = $custom_query->max_num_pages;
    $big = 999999999;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
// END Pagination
```

It works for me